# Reading serial data from thermal camera MLX90640/GY-MCU90640 with Raspberry Pi 4 returns garbage characters

Tags: serial, pi-4, uart

I am trying to read data from an MLX90640 thermal camera using the GY-MCU90640 board based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/vvkuryshev/GY-MCU90640-RPI-Python/).

```
VIN is connected to 5V (4)
GND is connected to GND (6)
RX is connected to TX/GPIO14 (8)
TX is connected to RX/GPIO15 (10)
```

Serial is enabled without login shell using `sudo raspi-config`/Interfacing/Serial.
I2C is disabled using `sudo raspi-confi`/Interfacing/I2C.

However, when trying to read some data using the following Python script, I only receive weird characters such as `i)2iKbi!��(R�Bi!�(�ke�+ik`. At least the lines are changing when moving my hand above the sensor, so I assume it is kind of working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/serial0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)

while 1:
        ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0xA5,0x15,0x01,0xBB]))  # configure for 9600 kbps baud rate
        x=ser.readline()
        print x
```

Not surprisingly the [proposed `main.py` script](https://github.com/vvkuryshev/GY-MCU90640-RPI-Python/) to read thermal images fails with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'`.

Comment: There's a lot more in the program given in the tutorial.  Have you tried it as released by the author?  Sending the configuration string within your `while` loop looks particularly suspicious.

Comment: @BobBrown indeed, I moved it above the loop, but still no luck. The `main.py` script fails with errors like `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'`.

Comment: how do you know that the data is garbage?

Answer (score 2):

GY-MCU90640 modules I have seen had a default baudrate of 115200, not 9600. Since your symptoms look exactly like baudrate mismatch, this is the first thing I would try to rectify.

Note that GY-MCU90640 also has an I2C interface which is much faster (around 400000 instead of 115200) and doesn't have any configuration options you can get wrong as the UART interface does. I would definitely use that instead of the UART.

Answer (score 0):

When I see strange characters like this I immediately think about the serial setup. I would play around with the combination of baud rate, parity, byte size and stop bits until I got readable text coming back.

I note that the default baud rate (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTEKa.png)) for the device is 115200 and it seems they are proposing 8 bit word, no stop bit and no parity. Try something like:

*ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/serial0',
        baudrate = 115200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1*

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tested 9600 and 115200, with both I receive stuff like `)MC�v�|����dkC`. With 460800 I do not receive anything. Configurations mentioned in the manual (e.g. `ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0xA5,0x15,0x03,0xBD]))`) do not change anything.

Comment: Is there anything on the Raspberry 4 which could disturb the communication such as Bluetooth mentioned for older models?

Comment: Given you have 2 unknowns, what the RPi serial connection is up to and the settings for the thermal camera module it might be a good strategy to split up the problem. I use Coolterm on my Mac (also runs on Windows) to work with devices that use a serial connection. It's easy to setup and change through the various combinations of serial port settings and you'll get immediate feedback when you get the values correct. Take a look at https://www.mac-usb-serial.com/docs/tutorials/access-serial-port-on-mac-with-coolterm.html or https://coolterm.en.lo4d.com/windows for more information.